# Bug in quicksort example (K&R C book)?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, qsort, undefined-behavior

This quicksort is supposed to sort "v[left]...v[right] into increasing order"; copied (without comments) from The C Programming Language by K&R (Second Edition):

```
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(int v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
        if (v[i] < v[left])
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
```

I think there's a bug at

```
(left + right) / 2
```

Suppose left = INT_MAX - 1 and right = INT_MAX. Wouldn't this result in undefined behavior due to integer overflow?

Comment: It was probably programmed with the assumption that an array wouldn't be that large at runtime. :)

Comment: That's a very good assumption since you wouldn't have space in memory for your quicksort program

Comment: See also: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: @functionptr can you please answer this question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534487/quick-sort-programmed-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're right. You can use `left - (left - right) / 2` to avoid overflows.

Comment: @Jerry / Paul: Which, since `(right - left) == - (left - right)`, is the same as this answer's formulation.

Comment: @caf: Ah, I hadn't thought of it that way, but you're right. I rescind my original comment, and apologize for being obtuse.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't imagining an array with `INT_MAX` number of elements, are you?

Comment: That's just under 8 gigabytes of address space, assuming 32-bit integers. More than doable on modern hardware. :)

Comment: We would probably have to excuse K&R for not considering memory growing from kB to GB. And "640k should be enough for everyone"?

Comment: @Bo there are platforms with 16-bit `int`s, you know, and I'm pretty sure some of them have more than 64Kb of memory. `int` != `intptr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, although it's possibly just written that way for simplicity -- it's an example after all, not production code.

Answer (score 1):

K&R was always a bit sloppy with their use of unsigned vs signed arguments.  Side effect of working with a PDP that had only 16 kilobytes of memory I suppose. That's been fixed a while ago.  The current definition of qsort is

```
void qsort(
   void *base,
   size_t num,
   size_t width,
   int (__cdecl *compare )(const void *, const void *) 
);
```

Note the use of size_t instead of int.  And of course void* base since you don't know what kind of type you are sorting.

Comment: The `__cdecl` wart isn't a part of the standard definition.

Comment: I'm sure that's true, they probably had only *one* calling convention back then.  And a lot less keywords that started with *two* underscores.  Leave it up to the vendors to make it complicated.  Necessarily so, the standard kinda sux.