# why left+(right-left)/2 will not overflow?

Tags: integer-overflow

In this article: http://googleresearch.blogspot.sg/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html, it mentioned most quick sort algorithm had a bug (left+right)/2, and it pointed out that the solution was using `left+(right-left)/2` instead of `(left+right)/2`. 
The solution was also given in question [Bug in quicksort example (K&R C book)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486947/bug-in-quicksort-example-kr-c-book)

My question is why `left+(right-left)/2` can avoid overflow? How to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have `left < right` by definition.

As a consequence, `right - left > 0`, and furthermore `left + (right - left) = right` (follows from basic algebra).

And consequently `left + (right - left) / 2 <= right`. So no overflow can happen since every step of the operation is bounded by the value of `right`.

---

By contrast, consider the buggy expression, `(left + right) / 2`. `left + right >= right`, and since we don’t know the values of `left` and `right`, it’s entirely possible that that value overflows.

Answer (score 15):

Suppose (to make the example easier) the maximum integer is 100, `left = 50`, and `right = 80`. If you use the naive formula:

```
int mid = (left + right)/2;
```

the addition will result in `130`, which overflows.

If you instead do:

```
int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
```

you can't overflow in `(right - left)` because you're subtracting a smaller number from a larger number. That always results in an even smaller number, so it can't possibly go over the maximum. E.g. `80 - 50 = 30`.

And since the result is the average of `left` and `right`, it must be between them. Since these are both less than the maximum integer, anything between them is also less than the maximum, so there's no overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Basic logic.

1. by definition `left <= MAX_INT`
2. by definition `right <= MAX_INT`
3. `left+(right-left)` is equal to `right`, which already is `<= MAX_INT` per #2
4. and so `left+(right-left)/2` **must** also be `<= MAX_INT` since `x/2` is always smaller than `x`.

Compare to the original

1. by definition `left <= MAX_INT`
2. by definition `right <= MAX_INT`
3. therefore `left+right <= MAX_INT`
4. and so `(left+right)/2 <= MAX_INT`

where statement 3 is clearly false, since `left` can be `MAX_INT` (statement 1) and so can `right` (statement 2).

Answer (score 7):

A simple worked example will show it.  For simplicity, assume numbers overflow above `999`.  If we have:

```
left = 997
right = 999
```

then:

```
left + right = 1996
```

which has overflown before we get to the `/2`.  However:

```
right - left = 2
(right-left)/2 = 1
left + (right-left)/2 = 997 + 1 = 998
```

So we've avoided the overflow.

More generally (as others have said): If both `left` and `right` are within range (and assuming `right > left`, then `(right-left)/2` will be within range and so too must `left + (right-left)/2` since this must be less than `right` (since you've increased `left` by half the gap between it and `right`.

Comment: incorrect calculation left=997 right=999 left+right =1996 not 1995

Answer (score 6):

As int data type is 32 bit in Java (Assuming a programming language), any value that surpasses 32 bits gets rolled over. In numerical terms, it means that after incrementing 1 on Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647), the returned value will be -2147483648.

**Coming to the question above lets assume the following:**

```
int left = 1;
int right = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int mid;
```

**Case 1:**

```
mid = (left +right)/2; 
//Here the value of left + right would be -2147483648 which would overflow.
```

**Case 2:**

```
mid = left + (right - left)/2;
//This would not have the same problem as above as the value would never exceed "right".
```

**In theory:**

Both the values are same as *left + (right - left)/2 = (2*left + right - left)/2 = (left + right)/2*

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

(This is more an intuitive explanation than a proof.)

Assume your data is `unsigned char`, and `left = 100` and `right = 255` (so `right` as at the edge of the range).
If you do `left + right`, you'll get 355, which does not fit the `unsigned char` range, so it will overflow.

However, `(right-left)/2` is a quantity `X` such that `left + X < right < MAX`, where `MAX` is 255 for `unsigned char`. This way, you can be sure that the sum can never overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not m = (l - r) / 2? Since we do not need already traversed indexes where from the start to the current left?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).